# Protocol message contained an invalid tag 0

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

My goal is to create a realtime service alert feed and send it over to a server that I made in Java with an HTTP post request. The first step I did was to create a copy of the example alert feed posted here and it seems I was successfully able to do that as I was able to print it out the message. https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/alerts

The next step that I did is to create an HTTP connection and send the feed over with the POST request. This is what I have in my client code and example here is the feed name.

```
String url = "https://localhost:8080";
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf");
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
example.build().writeDelimitedTo(wr);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

My server code is simply this so far.

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080); 
System.out.println("Listening for connection on port 8080 ...."); 
while (true) { 
    try (Socket socket = server.accept()) {
      FeedMessage feed = FeedMessage.parseDelimitedFrom(socket.getInputStream());
      Date today = new Date(); 
      String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + today; 
      socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8")); 
      }     
}
```

The question here is that I get the Protocol message contained an invalid tag 0 on the server side. I would like some help on trying to resolve this issue. Maybe I am not parsing it correctly.

Update #2

I have tried to parse the HTTP headers to get to the payload like comments have said. But my code hangs and the output to print the headers on the terminal looks serialized.

```
    DataInputStream isr = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(isr); 
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(reader);  
    String line = reader2.readLine();
    System.out.println("get lines");
    while (!line.isEmpty()) { 
         System.out.println(line); 
         line = reader2.readLine(); 
     }
```

Comment: You're trying to use HTTP and a DataOutputStream on one side, and parse that as a protocol buffer on the other side. That's nonsensical: those are totally different wire fornats.

Comment: What is the best solution for this? I believe I actually tried to parse it as a http response instead as a protocol buffer and when I printed it out it was serialized and I think that was due to the writeDelimitedTo() in the client side.

Comment: With the edit with bufferedreader: do you see the headers correctly *then* garbage? Note: bufferedreader will try to parse the payload as text, corrupting the non-text payload; and because it is buffered, it will over-read, so you can't simply stop using it and go back to the stream.  In short you can't use bufferedreader to parse the headers of an http request that has a binary payload without screwing up the payload. You'd have to parse the headers as binary.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with raw sockets at the server, but the payload is encoded in an http request body. You are going to need to parse the http request through to the payload, and *when you have just the body* : send that to protobuf. Right now, you're sending the http headers to protobuf, which doesn't make sense. That could mean parsing through to `\r\n\r\n`, but it would help if you could make use of the content-length header, and even better if you can use a pre-built http library.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I believe I tried to parse through the HTTP headers already.